# sup$_{x\in S}x$ notation for lim sup/inf

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

What does the following notation 'sup$_{x\in S}x$' mean in the context of limit superior and inferior? I am asking because usually I see it used like 'sup$X$' for some set $X$, but here it seems as if an element is passed to it.

Comment: I would interpret that as the supremum of the set $S$. I don't know why the author chose to use that notation but it may simply be preference.

Comment: This is a special case of the fairly common notation $\sup_{\phi(x)}f(x)$ where $f$ is a function and where $\phi(x)$ is a statement about $x$. It  means $\sup\{f(x):\phi(x)\}$. So the expression in your question means $\sup\{x:x\in S\}$, which is, as @CyclotomicField said, a long-winded way to say $\sup S$.